# Opening connection and writing table as UTF-8 moves items in first row

Tags: r, csv, utf-8

I have a `d`ataframe that looks like this:

```
> head(d,4)
             file_name        node component
1       a-bom.wr-p-e-a       a-bom  wr-p-e-a
2    abessijn.wr-p-e-a    abessijn  wr-p-e-a
3 accelerator.wr-p-e-g accelerator  wr-p-e-g
4 accelerator.wr-p-e-l accelerator  wr-p-e-l
```

My column names are obvious:

```
> colnames(d)
[1] "file_name" "node"      "component"
```

However, when exporting as csv with an encoding to UTF-8, something goes wrong with the colnames. I export the file as follows:

```
con <- file("../R/dataset/r-dataset.csv", open="w", encoding="UTF-8")
write.table(df, con, sep="\t")
close(con)
```

Bu when I do so the first row moves to the left, in place of where the empty cell for for the index column is. It looks like this:

[image]

So *only the first row* moved to fill the gap. They all have to move on cell to the right. I don't understand why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Try `write.table()` with `row.names = FALSE`

Comment: @RichardScriven But this will remove the index column all together. That's not what I want.

Comment: in that case, `d$row <- 1:nrow(d)` then use `row.names = FALSE`

Comment: Or you could try `col.names = c("", colnames(d))`

Comment: @RichardScriven `Error in write.table(d, con, sep = "\t", col.names = c("", colnames(d))) : 
  invalid 'col.names' specification`

Comment: @jeremycg Tha't s cheating. `:D` Those aren't real indices. Also, this would require me to re-order my columns. I hope there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?write.table`:

> By default there is no column name for a column of row names.  If
>        ‘col.names = NA’ and ‘row.names = TRUE’ a blank column name is
>        added, which is the convention used for CSV files to be read by
>        spreadsheets.

So you should do:

```
con <- file("../R/dataset/r-dataset.csv", open="w", encoding="UTF-8")
write.table(df, con, sep="\t",col.names=NA)
close(con)
```